# wso2 Ballerina using DB Connections with Services

Tags: ballerina

I use ballerina 0.91 and try to do a REST GET Service for getting some data on an oracle databse. Following are the Oracle Info using on sql:ClientConnector.

```
service<http> MyService {

 @http:GET {}
 @http:Path {value: "/myService"}
 resource apiGET (message m) {

   string driverClass = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
   string dbURL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxx:1521:yyy";
   string username = "aaa";
   string password = "bbb";
   map propertiesMap = {"driverClassName":driverClass,"jdbcUrl":dbURL, "username":username, "password":password};
   sql:ClientConnector myConnection = create sql:ClientConnector(propertiesMap);

   <getting data from the database and prepare to send back to client>

   message response = {};
   messages:setJsonPayload(response, myData);        
   sql:ClientConnector.close(myConnection);        

   reply response;
 }
}
```

So using the DB Connection within each GET I have to open the connection to database and close it again at the end. This is time costly.

Alternatively I could open the DB Connection on the Service level, so outside the GET, this would open the DB Connection once and inside the GET I can always use the DB. This is very fast and in running the service inside Composer everything works fine even I use the GET with some clients in parallel several times, I do not run out of DB Connections.
But when I compile the Service an I run the service as

```
ballerina run -s myService.balx
```

so I run out of DB Connections and I get some exception.

How can I pool DB Connection in a way so that I can reuse a connection for each GET and before finishing the GET I send it back to the pool.
How I can close a DB Connection when the Service is shutdown?

Any general design hint is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SQL Client Connector will create a Connection Pool size of 10 by default. If you need to change the pool size you can pass properties as below.

```
sql:ConnectionProperties properties = {maximumPoolSize:5};
sql:ClientConnector testDB = create sql:ClientConnector(sql:MYSQL, "localhost", 3306, "db", "sa", "root", properties);
```

Declaring the connector on the Service level is the correct way. Then when you do SQL operations within GET it will get a connection from the pool and execute.

Apparently there is an issue in the connector when using it in .balx files. This has been reported as an issue in Github repository [1].

[1] https://github.com/ballerinalang/ballerina/issues/3222

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response, I use now 0.92 and changed my code according the new spec. As far as using it in the composer it works fine and as you write using the compiled (balx) version gets to some problem, so looking forward to a fix.

Comment: Hi, above issue has been fixed. Can you please check with 0.95 release?